# SubQuery on Single Table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, hierarchical-data

Ok so I have a table

```
Tasks
--
TaskId  (unique autoinc primary)
ChildOf   (Contains task ID of parent, or 0 if top tier (no parent))
```

I need to write a query that selects all records with ChildOf = 0 ...  Simple right ?

Ok but also need to have another column returned with the results that tells how many Children each Task has ...

So result would look like this ...

```
TaskID ...  ChildOf ... countChildren
 37   ......  0   ....    3
 42   ......  0   ....    0
 99   ......  0   ....    1 

etc....
```

I know the two queries I need are something like this, but need to combine them somehow...

```
Select TaskId as ParentTaskId, ChildOf from Tasks where ChildOf = 0
```

and

```
Select count(TaskId) from Tasks where ChildOf = ParentTaskId
```

NOTE:  There are only 2 tiers.. Parent and Child ... No Grandchildren!  So hopefully that makes it a bit less complicated.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: MySQL lacks the recursive functionality that is now ANSI.  The MySQL site used to have a great article about how to deal with hierarchical data in MySQL, but Oracle appears to have taken it down :/

Comment: But he only needs recursive functionality if he needs to get more than one level of children.  Otherwise it's a simple subquery.  So Brian, do you need just the count of the immediate nodes, or to count the entire tree (children of children).

Comment: Excellent Question... I just need the one level.. Parent -> Child   no grandchildren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT TaskId as ParentTaskId, ChildOf , 
 (SELECT count(t2.TaskId) 
  FROM Tasks t2
  WHERE t2.ChildOf = t.TaskId) as CountChildren
FROM Tasks t 
WHERE t.ChildOf = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.TaskID, T1.ChildOf, count(*) from 
  Tasks as T1 join Tasks as T2 on T1.TaskID = T2.ChildOf 
  WHERE T1.ChildOf = 0 
    GROUP BY (T1.TaskID)
```

Comment: This is very close but does not pull up the parents who have NO children

Comment: Instead of JOIN use a LEFT JOIN to get the parents with no children.